# issue with searchBar searching

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, swift4

I have issue with `UISearchBar` implementation. I have done must of the work but I have issue when I tried to search inside tableView

```
struct gameStruct: Codable {
    var id: String
    var image: String
    var gameName: String
    var gameDate: String
    var gameVideo: String

}
var filteredArray : [gameStruct] = []
var searchBar :UISearchController!
var shouldShowSearchResults = false

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = true
    //tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = false
    //tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if !shouldShowSearchResults {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredArray = gameV3.filter() {
        return $0.gameName.range(of: searchBar.searchBar.text!) != nil
    }
    updateSearchResults(for: searchBar)

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I got this error in line : `return $0.gameName.range(of: searchBar.searchBar.text!) != nil`

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee1c0aff8)`

FULL CODE ON GITHUB: https://github.com/iYousef911/UTGupToGame/blob/master/gameTableViewController.swift

Comment: Any error message in console?

Comment: where are you define gameV3

Comment: @Larme no error

Comment: What's the call stack? In `updateSearchResults()`, you call `updateSearchResults()` again?

Comment: @mohsen here is the code in GitHub : [link]https://github.com/iYousef911/UTGupToGame/blob/master/gameTableViewController.swift

Comment: @Larme someone help me out and tell me to add it before tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Any help in this issue ?

Comment: @yousef-abu-sallamah do you try it ?
`return $0.gameName.range(of: self.searchBar.searchBar.text!) != nil`

Comment: @mohsen yes still display all results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code on GitHub and tried to solve the crash. This is what I did with your updateSearchResults(). I have used the code you mentioned here in your Question and demonstrate the change in it. You can vary accordingly.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if searchBar.searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.searchBar.text == "" {
            inSearchMode = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }else{
            inSearchMode = true
            filteredArray = gameV3.filter() {
                
                let strGameName = $0.gameName
                let stringToCompare = searchBar.searchBar.text!
                
                if let range = strGameName.range(of: stringToCompare) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
```

This solves the crash and load the data of filteredArray in tableView

Comment: I got crash in this line of code :             gamesObject = filteredArray[indexPath.row] as! games

Comment: I have filteredArray as follows:
var filteredArray : [gameStruct] = []
please check which type you want and which are you using

Comment: Thanks I have fixed the issue I have changed             var gamesObject: games! to             var gamesObject: gameStruct!

Comment: I have a small issue when the result is displayed and try to press on the cell the tableView reload all data and won't let me to press that cell here is GIF image to explain what I mean http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/15185510049241.gif

Answer (score 0):

This method uses **UISearchBar** rather than swift 4's **UISearchBarController** since UISearchBarController is **not available for iOS 10** (a lot of devices still use iOS 10).

1. Conform your class to **UISearchBarDelegate**
2. Define your var for arrays & for checking if searching:

   ```
   var gameList = [gameStruct]() 
   var filteredGameList = [gameStruct]()
   var inSearchMode = false
   ```
3. Create outlet for UISearchBar

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
   ```
4. In viewDidLoad, set delegates for searchBar

   ```
   searchBar.delegate = self
   searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
   ```
5. Implement delegate method

   ```
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
           inSearchMode = false
           // to dismiss keyboard
           view.endEditing(true)
           tableView.reloadData()
       }else{
           inSearchMode = true
           let lower = searchBar.text!.lowercased()
           filteredGameList = gameList.filter({ (game: GameStruct) -> Bool in
               return (game.gameName?.lowercased().contains(lower))!
           })
           tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }
   ```
6. Implement tableView Delegates

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if inSearchMode {
           return filteredGameList.count
       }
      return gameList.count
   }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? YourCustomCell {
           let game: GameStruct!
           if inSearchMode {
               game = filteredGameList[indexPath.row]
           } else {
               game = gameList[indexPath.row]
           }
           return cell
       }
       return UITableViewCell()
   }
   ```

Comment: I got error in this line:         filteredGameList = gameList({ (game: GameStruct) -> Bool in
Use of undeclared type 'GameStruct'

Comment: change GameStruct to gameStruct

Comment: also I got this error Cannot call value of non-function type '[gameTableViewController.gameStruct]'

Comment: try by declaring your struct right outside your gameTableViewController

Comment: https://github.com/iYousef911/UTGupToGame/blob/master/gameTableViewController.swift this is updated file could you please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's pretty simple as subtle but inside your

```
return $0.gameName.range(of: searchBar.searchBar.text!) != nil
```

you're forcing Xcode to unwrap the value of `searchBar.text` which is an optional an then after unwrapping you're checking if it's nil.

Try to softly unwrap `searchBar.text` by using something like this:

```
filteredArray = gameV3.filter() {
    guard let text = searchBar.searchBar.text else {
        return false
    }
    return !$0.gameName.range(of: text) != nil
}
```

If this would be the solution I would be a bit confused, because usually Xcode throws an error message like `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping a optional value`. Would you mind to try?